# Facebook OAuth field mapping issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, mapping, field, facebook-oauth

I'm running a multilingual Drupal 7 website with a fair amount of modules, including the [Facebook OAuth module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth) (version 7.x-2.0-rc3).

I've got an issue with the Field Mapping functionality, which doesn't work in my case.

Fields on the Drupal register form are simply not populated by the module as they should be, except for the username field, which pre-filled with my Facebook username.

I enabled the modules' debug setting, which logged the following (some info's have been edited for privacy):

```
fbuser=stdClass Object
(
    [email] => xxxxx@subversion.be
    [name] => Constantin Aktelle
    [first_name] => Constantin
    [last_name] => Aktelle
    [age_range] => stdClass Object
        (
            [min] => 21
        )

    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1080532871978412/
    [gender] => male
    [locale] => fr_FR
    [timezone] => 1
    [updated_time] => 2013-04-20T15:22:50+0000
    [verified] => 1
    [id] => 1080532871978412
)
```

So the Facebook information is indeed there, but the module seems to be unable to map them correctly.

Note that the module settings are as follows:

> - "Prénom" mapped to "[first_name] Prénom"
> - "Nom" field mapped to "[last_name] Nom"
> - "Genre" field mapped to "[gender] Sexe"

I can't figure out how to solve this issue, and I'm not sure what is causing it. Have anyone experienced this issue and / or have an idea about how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post back here once I finally found a fix for my question, so here it is:

The issue was coming from an incompatibility of the Facebook Oauth module with multilingual websites. Once I set my user fields to be untranslatable, the issue was fixed.